# Clear Formatting for a Range, not the Selection

Tags: vba, ms-word, formatting

The `ClearFormatting` method only works with the Selection object. Can I clear formats of a range without losing the selection, and ideally without caching it and calling `Select`. I'd like to clear formats for a Range

I've tried some combinations of Find/Replace, e.g.

```
Sub ClearFormat(ByVal doc As Document)
    'doc.Content.Find.ClearFormatting  'WdStoryType.wdMainTextStory
    Dim target As Range
    Set target = doc.Content
    With target.Find
        .Replacement.Font.Name = "Regular" 'hoping this will reset to my normal style
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute "*", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

And also setting the whole document style to the "Normal" style, but no joy

Comment: You've probably tried this but it seems to work well on my end: ```myRange.Style = wdStyleNormal```. The selection is preserved and the range gets reset to "Normal"

Answer (score 4):

For example:

```
With ActiveDocument.Range
  .ParagraphFormat.Reset
  .Font.Reset
End With
```